# Matplotlib scatter marker size

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot a 3D scatter with `matplotlib`
The problem is that I can't change the marker's size
I have this

```
scat = plt.scatter([boid_.pos[0] for boid_ in flock],
                   [boid_.pos[1] for boid_ in flock],
                   [boid_.pos[2] for boid_ in flock], 
                   marker='o', s=5)
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for keyword argument 's'
```

Without that, the plot works fine. Where is the problem? Or is there another way to change the size?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This function takes in two args before the keyword args:

`scatter(x, y, s=20, ...)`

And you are passing in three, so you are specifying `s` twice (once implicitly and once explicitly).

Actually, I think you are trying to use the 2D scatter plot function instead of a 3D one.  You probably want to do this instead:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
Axes3D.scatter( ... )
```

Comment: Maybe I should have written it in my post, but I had `fig=plt.figure()` and `ax = Axes3D(fig)`  before. I still got an error if I use Axes3D.scatter: `TypeError: unbound method scatter() must be called with Axes3D instance as first argument (got list instance instead)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I figured it out, that doing `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')` and then `ax.scatter()` , I don't get an erro anymore. Your answer made me realize that maybe I had something wrong with the scatter. Thanks for your help